# Python: waiting for user input or callback, whichever comes first

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, callback

I have a chatbot that waits for a user input but also has a screen where users can click a button to choose an option. On my python code I can get the chosen option through a callback and I also have an infinite loop that awaits for a user input after the chatbot responds. I want to ask the user a question but allow them to either input an answer or choose an option from the screen. So I want something more or less like this:

```
inp = ""
while(True):
    answer, end = get_answer(inp)
    print('CHATBOT: '+ answer)
    if end = break
    if input by user:
         inp = input by user
    elif callback:
         inp = callback value
```

Of course the callbak or input from the user could take a while to be given so a timer is kind of not desirable. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use threads with a message queue:

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue
from datetime import datetime
import time

def chatbot(queue):
    while True:
        queue.put('CHATBOT: The time is now %s' % datetime.now())
        time.sleep(5)

def user_input(queue):
    while True:
        queue.put('USER: ' + raw_input())

queue = Queue()
chatbot_thread = Thread(target=chatbot, args=(queue,))
input_thread = Thread(target=user_input, args=(queue,))
chatbot_thread.start()
input_thread.start()
while True:
    print(queue.get())
```

Sample input/output:

```
CHATBOT: The time is now 2019-03-01 07:42:43.975000
hello world
USER: hello world
CHATBOT: The time is now 2019-03-01 07:42:48.976000
CHATBOT: The time is now 2019-03-01 07:42:53.977000
foo bar
USER: foo bar
CHATBOT: The time is now 2019-03-01 07:42:58.977000
```